# Thickbox doesn't close when Esc key is pressed when the iframe is focused

Tags: jquery, thickbox

When I focus the iframe and try to push the esc key to close the window, nothing happens. I assume that it is because the focused iframe is not subscribed to this event. Does anyone have any ideas how I could attach this event to the iframe without having to manually edit each one of the pages that are contained in a thickbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works in internet explorer, which happens to be the only browser my client base is using, however I would prefer a solution that at least works in firefox.

```
$("#TB_iframeContent").ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#TB_iframeContent').contents().find('body').keyup(function(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 27){
                tb_remove();
            }
        });
    }, 50);
  });
```

I add this at line 245 in the original thickbox source.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Flash in the iframe? It could be stealing your keyboard focus.

Comment: Is there a way to close the iframe even when it's running for example video?

Answer (score 0):

It does not work for security reasons. None of the events that happen inside the iframe are allowed to bubble out to the containing document.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this problem by replacing the line 245 of the thickbox.js file.

Just replaced:

```
if(!params['modal']){
```

with

```
if(params['modal'] != "true"){
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this in your code

```
$('#TB_iframeContent').ready(function(){

    setTimeout(function(){
        $(window).keyup(function(e){
                  if(e.keyCode == 27){
                    $('#TB_closeWindowButton').click();
          }
            }); 
        }, 50);

});
```